# OperationalError: table "django_session" already exists

Tags: python, django

I have applied all solutions I could find, but still I got an operational error and also when I run project it gives error like:

> You have 1 unapplied migration(s).....

I had applied all migrations.

I tried this solution:

1. Delete all files under migrations directory except `init.py` (successfully)
2. run `$python manage.py makemigrations <appname>` (successfully)
3. run `$python manage.py sqlmigrate <appname> 001` (Successfully)
4. run `$python manage.py migrate` (Failed: operational error)

Because of 4th failure I got a statement of migrations while I ran project

What should I do?

Below is my code:

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [  url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'), url(r'.*signup/$' , views.signup.as_view(), name='signup'),  ]
```

`models.py`

```
class PatientSignup(models.Model):
    Pname = models.CharField()
```

`forms.py`:

```
class PatientSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    forms.CharField()  # add other fileds
```

`views.py`:

```
class signup(TemplateView):
    temp = 'personal/signup.html'

    def get(self, request):
        psform = PatientSignupForm()
        data = PatientSignup.objects.all()
        args = {'psform': psform, 'data': data}
        return render(request, self.temp, args)


    def post(self, request):
        psform = PatientSignupForm(request.POST)
        if psform.is_valid():
            psform.save()
        cd = psform.cleaned_data
        args = {'psform': psform, 'data': data}
        return render(request, self.temp, args)
```

Template code:

```
<form method="post">
    { % csrf_token %}
    <div>
        {{psform.as_p}}
        <button type="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show us the code, that you've came up with so far. Only a Minimal Example, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 0) Delete the database and create it again or delete all entries in the table `django_migrations` and try again the migrations.

Comment: The second advice is actually how he got into this jam, as you can see by the raised error in the post title. It's almost never good advice to give. If you clear django_migrations, you should clear all model tables. The only reason to do this instead of dropping the database is that Django isn't the only user of the database and so dropping the database is not a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to apply migrations on already created database field. You could have run migrate --fake command, but in your case, it seems that you have multiple migrations to migrate. First of all, delete your current db by creating a backup of it. Now type,

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

At this point, you have created migration files, enter following command,

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This should have solved your migrations issue. Thanks